# Routing in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have a super simple controller with 2 methods:

```
public IActionResult Users(long id)
{
    return Json(new { name = "Example User" });
}

public IActionResult Users()
{
    return Json(new { list = new List<User>() });
}
```

One to select all users and the other to return all users. In web api 2 I could user the following route and everything worked fine:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Users",
                routeTemplate: "v1/Users",
                defaults: new { action = "Users", controller = "Users" },
                constraints: null,
                handler: new TokenValidationHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
            );
```

I have the following routes setup in startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "User_Default", template: "v1/{controller=Users}/{action=Users}/{id?}");
            });
```

However this gives me a `AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have an attribute `Route` on your controller, which is there in many templates. Can you provide your whole controller?

Comment: @MattDeKrey I don't as I didn't think that they would be needed if I simply set my routes up like webapi 2 routes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original webapi code, you were using `Routes.MapHttpRoute` which adds webapi specific routes. This is different from an MVC route which won´t take into account the parameters in the action, for instance you would have the same problem in MVC 5 if you were using `Routes.MapRoute`.

The same thing is happening in your MVC 6 code, since you are adding a standard MVC route using `routes.MapRoute`. In both cases the framework is finding 2 controller actions matching the same route with no additional constraints. It needs some help in order to select one of those 2 actions.

The easiest way to disambiguate the api actions would be using attribute routing instead of defining a route, as in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api-mac#getting-to-do-items):

```
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Users(long id)
    {
        return Json(new { name = "Example User" });
    }

    public IActionResult Users()
    {
        return Json(new { list = new[] { "a", "b" } });
    }
}
```

There are other options that would let you change the behaviour of the MVC routing in MVC 6. You could create your own `IActionConstraint` attribute to enforce having or not a given parameter. That way one of those actions requires an id parameter in the route while the other requires not to have an id parameter (Warning, untested code):

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [RouteParameterConstraint("id", ShouldAppear=true)]
    public IActionResult Users(long id)
    {
        return Json(new { name = "Example User" });
    }

    [RouteParameterConstraint("id", ShouldNotAppear=true)]
    public IActionResult Users()
    {
        return Json(new { list = new[] { "a", "b" } });
    }
}

public class RouteParameterConstraintAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    private routeParameterName;

    public RouteParameterConstraintAttribute(string routeParameterName)
    {
        this.routerParamterName = routerParameterName;
    }

    public int Order => 0;
    public bool ShouldAppear {get; set;}
    public bool ShouldNotAppear {get; set;}

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        if(ShouldAppear) return context.RouteContext.RouteData.Values["country"] != null;
        if(ShouldNotAppear) return context.RouteContext.RouteData.Values["country"] == null;

        return true;
    }
}
```

A better option to deal with webapi 2 style controllers would be adding conventions into the MVC pipeline. This is exactly what the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` is doing to help migrating webapi 2 controllers. You can see the conventions added [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/WebApiCompatShimOptionsSetup.cs). Check [this guide](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/) for a quick overview of this package.

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer but I'd also love to know why specifying the route in the startup.cs file doesn't work

Comment: @Gazeth, I have added more details to my answer

Comment: Links https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/WebApiCompatShimOptionsSetup.cs and https://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6 are dead

Comment: Updated. Also got rid of the RouteConstraintAttribute in favor or IActionConstraint