# How might I simultaneously bind FromQuery and FromRoute parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding, .net-core

I am needing to simultaneously support a query-parameter based route (`/api/models?id=1`) and a route based one (`/api/models/1`) while still allowing unambiguous access to the models collection (`/api/models`)?

My controller looks (something) like this:

```
[Route("/api/{controller}")]
public class ModelsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Models[] GetModels([FromQuery]QueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        //...
    }    

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public Model Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet("?{id:int}")]
    public Model Get2Try1([FromQuery] int id)
    {
       //Fails with ": The literal section '?' is invalid. 
       //Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character."
       //Which makes sense after some reading...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Model Get2Try2([FromQuery] int id)
    {
       //Fails with "AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. 
       //The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: 
       //GetModels and Get2Try2"
       //Which I think I understand as well...the absence of optional params
       //means ambiguous routing...
    }

    [HttpGet] //What here?
    public Model Get2Try3([FromQuery] int id) //and/or here?
    {

    }
}
```

I feel like there should be some way to (with declarative routing) accomplish this. Has anyone done anything along these lines?

Also, current code base is ASP.NET Core (RC1) to be upgraded to RTM/1.0 shortly. Details on either side are likely similar, but am interested in either/both.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the following works:

```
[HttpGet, Route("{id?}")]
```

... the key being mainly the '?'. You don't need any [FromX] in the method signature, this does the trick and caters for both query string and route parameter passing.

Unfortunately Swagger UI doesn't like it and expects some explicit parameter to work out of the box (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/issues/47 or https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/issues/182), but that's another story :)

Comment: This does not work for me. It works as [FromRoute] and does not work as [FromQuery]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
There aren't solutions that works (against wep api .net) with web api core.
If we set [Route("{id}")] and [Route("")] doesn't work; if we set only [Route("{id?}")] the query parameter is empty if I use querystring.

So, I've used a workround.
I used [Route("{id?}")], but inside the function I get param from Request.Query

Example

```
public T Cast<T>(string input)
{
        T output = default(T);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return output;

        input = input.Trim();
        try
        {
            Type typeToCastTo = typeof(T);

            if (typeof(T).IsGenericType)
                typeToCastTo = typeToCastTo.GenericTypeArguments[0];

            if (typeToCastTo.IsEnum)
            {
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeToCastTo, input))
                    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeToCastTo, input);
                return output;
            }


            object value = Convert.ChangeType(input, typeToCastTo, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return (value == null) ? output : (T)value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return output;
        }
}

public void MapQuerystringParams<T>(ref T param, string name)
{
        var q = Request.Query[name].FirstOrDefault();
        if (q != null)
        {
            var cast = Cast<T>(q);
            if (!cast.Equals(default(T)))
                param = cast;
        }

}

[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]    
[ApiController]
public class ActivityController : ControllerBase
{
    //examples of call 
    //https://localhost:44345/api/Activity/GetActivityByCode/7000
    //https://localhost:44345/api/Activity/GetActivityByCode/?Id=7000

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{Id?}")]
    public IActionResult GetActivityByCode(int Id)
    {
        MapQuerystringParams(ref Id, "Id"); //this take param from querystring if exists

        ActivityBusiness business = new ActivityBusiness(new BusinessInitializer { config = configuration });

        ActivityDTOModel activity = business.GetActivityByCode(Id);

        return Ok(activity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally in the domain design if you can have one method serving one specific function then great. Recently I had to faithfully implement a legacy API and it wasn't an option for me to decompose the design of my API.

If you are suffering from ambiguous routes in MVC6 and need to differentiate unique Routes given specific QueryStrings that have been supplied at one single POST method. Then IActionConstraint can help!  Here is some example code of me using it :

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints;

    namespace Automation.Api.Service.Attributes
    {
        public class RoutingSpecificAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
        {
            private string _keyParam;

            public RoutingSpecificAttribute(string routingParameter)
            {
                this._keyParam = routingParameter;
            }


            public int Order
            {
                get
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
            {
                if (this._keyParam == null) { return true; }

                switch (this._keyParam)
                {
                    case "name": return context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(this._keyParam);
                    case "noquerystring": return context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Count == 0;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This one method in the API that I needed to author both serviced a separate create + update functions based on the existence of a couple of QueryStrings: name & version.

So to help disambiguate you can distinctly decorate each of the methods within your controllers within said controller class  [RoutingSpecific("noquerystring")]  or [RoutingSpecific("name")] to help differentiate.

[MSDN class description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.iactionconstraint?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

[Example implementation - see Entropy github](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/master/samples/Mvc.ActionConstraintSample.Web)

Comment: Probably a complicated way of doing something like this but it was a means to an end for me.

Comment: Also answered here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958798/routing-in-mvc-6

Answer (score -1):

For anyone that happens to stumble upon this as I have,

Using .Net Core 3.1 the following works:

#### Web Controller Method

```cs
[HttpGet("something/{id}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] id, [FromQuery] OptionalParams optionalParams) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

#### Query Parameter Container

```cs
public class OptionalParams 
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "colour_of_thing")]
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "shape_of_thing")]
    public string Shape { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "some_other_filter")]
    public string SomeOtherFilter { get; set; }
}
```

#### Url

```cs
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var colour = "red";
var shape = "circle";

var url = $"Http://localhost:5000/something/{id}?colour_of_thing={colour}&shape_of_thing={shape}";
```