# ASP.NET Core 6 : FromQuery params are breaking controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

Here's an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API controller method (it's marked `async` because once I build it out it will be actually async):

```
[HttpGet("{thingId}/parts")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(
    [FromRoute] int thingId)
    => Ok(await Task.FromResult("HELLO"));
```

The client application sends a `GET` request to

```
https://localhost:44345/api/things/17/parts?firstDate=2018-04-01&lastDate=2023-06-30
```

This works. The client receives "HELLO". Also, when I set a breakpoint on the last line, execution breaks there.

Next, I add `FromQuery` parameters to the controller to capture the dates in the URI query:

```
[HttpGet("{thingId}/parts")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(
    [FromRoute] int thingId,
    [FromQuery] string firstDate,
    [FromQuery] string lastDate)
    => Ok(await Task.FromResult("HELLO"));
```

Now the client gets an error status code and execution *doesn't* stop at the breakpoint. What's going on?

ADDITIONAL INFO: From the logs, I see that it *is* identifying the controller correctly, and is getting stuck on the parameters. Showing firstDate lines only, lastDate lines are likewise. Log lines truncated intentionally:

```
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3493256Z","@m":"Attempting to bind parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"System.String\"' ...","
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3494690Z","@m":"Attempting to bind parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"System.String\"' using the name '\"\"' in request data ...","@i":
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3498468Z","@m":"Could not find a value in the request with name '\"\"' for binding parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"System.String\"'.","
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3498781Z","@m":"Done attempting to bind parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3498944Z","@m":"Done attempting to bind parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3499122Z","@m":"Attempting to validate the bound parameter '\"firstDate\"' of 
{"@t":"2023-06-30T19:40:21.3563405Z","@m":"Done attempting to validate the bound parameter '\"firstDate\"'
```

It finds the named parameters `firstDate` and `lastDate`, but then it says, for each, `Could not find a value in the request with the name '\"\"'` (or, unescaped, `'""'`). I don't know what to make of that.

MORE DETAILS: I noticed on the second line of the above log `Attempting to bind parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"System.String\"' using the name '\"\"'`, I tried this:

```
[FromQuery(Name = "firstDate")] string firstDate,
[FromQuery(Name = "lastDate")] string lastDate)
```

That didn't fix the problem. Same log messages, except that now it says
`Attempting to bind parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"System.String\"' using the name '\"firstDate\"'` on the second line related to `Could not find a value in the request with the name '\"firstDate\"' for binding parameter '\"firstDate\"' of type '\"System.String\"'` on the third line.

NEXT ITERATION: I changed the data type for the parameters from `string` to `string?`, and now execution *did* stop at the breakpoint, and it returned "HELLO" to the client when I resumed execution. However, what I discovered at the breakpoint is that firstDate and lastDate were both `null` rather than the values from the query string, *and* I'm still getting exactly the same log messages. So the only difference between before and now is that when it doesn't find the query parameters with those names, the `null` it wants to set the method parameters to is now OK because `string?` will accept it, whereas `string` didn't. I'm still having the problem where it simply isn't finding the query parameters by their names.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. What error are you getting? What is in the logs?

Comment: I've added pertinent log info to my post. The controller is being correctly identified, but then it's failing on the date parameters. In particular, I'm confused by the "Could not find a value in the request with the name '""' " lines. Each occurs after the application has already recognized the parameter's name.

Comment: There is not enough info can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: I'm not sure it can handler FromRoute and FromQuery at the same time. Do you even need the decorations, try without them and let it figure out whatever the hell it wants to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731777/how-might-i-simultaneously-bind-fromquery-and-fromroute-parameter

Comment: I happen to have just tried without the decorations, same result. It seems strange not to allow FromParam and FromRoute together. We're using FromRoute with FromBody in some places, successfully.

Comment: The code is just fine. Make sure that you are actually using correct url with all parameters used. How do you make the request? Browser? Postman? Make the parameters optional and check the `Request.Query.Keys` values for the query params (and validate what keys are present).

Answer (score 0):

I did the same test on my computer and it works fine.
Verify that in **program.cs** you have **app.UseRouting()**

Comment: AFAIK with modern templates `UseRouting` call is not even required (it will be performed).